# AngularJS - uiView -> open Modal when clicking a link in footer

Tags: angularjs

I use AngularJS and I have the following template_

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="as-container">
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div class="apoSoftContainer">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-md-12 column" ui-view="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="as-footer">
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

A span- Tag in my Footer looks like this:

```
</span> Version <span style="font-weight:normal;">Some Text</span></span>
```

There is no controller or service for the footer.
My aim is that when I click onto "Some Text" than a modal should be open but I don't know where to place the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already got the code to open a modal, I suggest you create a controller for it.

I usually wrap my entire application using a "mainController". That way, I can use it for head elements, footer, etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="WebApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">
<head>
     <title>{{main.myTitle}}</title>
</head>
</body>
     <footer>
        <span ng-click="main.openModal()">Click here!</span>
     </footer>
</body>
</html>
```